# negative Euler characteristic $\Rightarrow$ homotopy unique up to homotopy

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, homotopy-theory

In a paper by John Franks I stumbled upon the following:

Let $M$ be a surface  and $f:M \rightarrow M$ be a 
homeomorphism, which is homotopic to the identity on $M$. That means, that there is  continuous map $h: [0,1] \times M \rightarrow M$, such that $h(0,\cdot) = id_M$ and
$h(1,\cdot)= f$.

If $M$ has negative Euler characteristic, then the homotopy is unique up to homotopy. (i.e. if there is another homotopy $g: [0,1] \times M \rightarrow M$, such that $g(0,\cdot) = id_M$ and $g(1,\cdot)= f$, then $h$ and $g$ are homotopic).

In Frank's paper, the surface $M$ is additionally equipped with a riemannian metric of constant negative curvature and of genus zero. I don't know if this is essential.

Currently, I have no idea why this is true. Can anyone explain or point me to a reference, where this is proved?

Comment: Is "genus zero" a typo?

Comment: No, it's not a typo. The surfaces we are talking about look very much like an open Annulus $S^1 \times (0,1)$ with a finite number of points removed. Such a surface is of genus 0 and negative Euler characteristic.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking of closed surfaces.

Comment: This phenomenon has (almost) nothing to do with negative Euler characteristic or surfaces. What you need is that the target space is $K(G,1)$. Now, just use Whitehead's theorem that maps to such targets are determined up to homotopy by maps of fundamental groups.

Comment: And then: negatively curved metric spaces have contractible universal covers, hence are $K(G,1)$s.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks alot for the hints! I found the following proposition in the Algebraic Topology Hatcher:

**Prop 1B.9** *Let $X$ be a connected CW complex and let $Y$ be a $K(G,1)$ space. Then every homomorphism
$\Pi_1(X,x_0) \rightarrow \Pi_1(Y,y_0)$ is induced by a map $(X,x_0) \rightarrow (Y,y_0)$
that is unique up to homotopy fixing $x_0$.*

Now, our maps $g,h$ are both homotopic to the identity and  hence induce the same homomorphism
on the fundamental group. It follows from the proposition that $g$ and $h$ are homotopic.